# PHP is not loaded as a module of Apache

Tags: php, linux, pthreads, ubuntu-14.04, lamp

I'm currently developing a web page with ***PHP***, and I had to install **Pthread** extension, I made it in the server (Ubuntu 14) so, before I had all working well, the problem came when I installed the extension, to install this extension I had to compile the php to make the needed configurations of PHP. Now, when I open a simple page, apache shows me the php code, it means that php is not interpreting or is not loaded in the modules of apache.

I went to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` but there's nothing of PHP, but in the linux terminal PHP is working well (so, it's installed). then I made:

```
sudo a2enmod php5
```

And I get this response:
    ERROR: Module php5 does not exist!

then , I made:

```
a2query -m php5
```

but I get:

```
No module matches php5
```

I have installed PHP 5.6version, so how can I enable this module in apache. I cannot install the standar version of PHP, I need this one for the mentioned reason. Thanks!

Comment: Did you install the apache2 php module? libapache2-mod-php5 or equivalent. Modules are not all included with apache in distros.

Comment: @osallou in the beggining yes, but then when I compiled my current version I uninstalled all of PHP. If I install libapache2-mod-php5 it modifies   my installed php?

Comment: @osallou I made it and it works now man! thank you very much! I thought it was to replace my current installation

Answer (score 2):

Apache needs a PHP module to execute PHP. In some distros (Debian, etc.) there is a specific package for this. In Ubuntu: libapache2-mod-php5

It does not impact the php installation install but only adds the apache module.

Once installed, one only need to activate the module.